What is the Alberto Moravia Prize?
The bios of two authors, Javier Marías and Anita Desai, often state that they were awarded the Alberto Moravia Prize in 2000. Here for instance is a Marías bio from Google Books:

Javier Marías is an award-winning Spanish novelist. He is also a translator and columnist, as well as the current king of Redonda.... In 1997 he won the Nelly Sachs Award; the Comunidad de Madrid award in 1998; in 2000 the Grinzane Cavour Award, the Alberto Moravia Prize, and the Dublin IMPAC Award. He also won the Spanish National Translation Award in 1979 for his translation of Tristram Shandy in 1979. He was a professor at Oxford University and the Complutense of Madrid. He currently lives in Madrid.

Here is part of a Desai bio from Goodreads:

A fellow of the Royal Society of Literature in London, the American Academy of Arts and Letters in New York, Girton College and Clare Hall at the University of Cambridge, and most recently Sahitya Akademi in India, Anita Desai has also been a Professor of Writing at MIT and has frequently been honoured with awards, among them the Alberto Moravia Prize for Literature.

What is this alleged Alberto Moravia Prize? Who sponsors it? What are the criteria? Who other than these two authors have won it? Aside from the occasional page associated with Desai or Marías stating that they have won it, I have been unable to find any information about this prize online. Searching for "Alberto Moravia Prize" mostly brings up pages lamenting the fact that he was not awarded the Nobel, alas.

Some more information on the somewhat mysterious Alberto Moravia prize can be found on the website of L’Associazione Fondo Alberto Moravia ("The Alberto Moravia Fund Association"). Translating the page, we learn that the Association:

... was established on 16 December 1991, following the death of the
writer, on the initiative of his sisters Adriana Pincherle and Elena
Pincherle Cimino, the heirs Carmen Llera (his widow)and Dacia
Maraini (his one-time partner) and some friends of Moravia, in particular
Giovanna Cau and Enzo Siciliano; the latter was President from 1991 to
2000.

The first aim of the Association was to inventory and catalogue Moravia's papers and effects, and create a study centre for Moravia scholars. Later the Association instituted the "Alberto Moravia Prize" for literature, which awarded prizes annually between 1993 and 2003 in several different categories:

Prize for Italian and foreign fiction
Prize for a degree thesis inspired by the life and/or work of Moravia
Prize for children's drawings inspired by Le storie della Preistoria by Moravia
Prize for a screenplay based on his work.

Javier Marías was awarded a prize in the eighth edition of the Alberto Moravia Prize in December 2000 in the category of foreign fiction, and the El País article notes that the Italian fiction prize for that year was awarded to Giuseppe Pontiggia. The prizes were decided by a jury, but I have not been able to find further details on its composition.
As noted in the question, the prize has also been awarded to Anita Desai (also in 2000, apparently), and Ian Mcewan has also been a recipient. It seems that the Association does not maintain a list of winners, but as the prizes were only awarded over the course of a decade, the number of winners must be quite limited.
